# How to map an entire site to two different contexts in a single war file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, war, servlet-filters

I'm developing a servlet filter, and I've written a diagnostics site to verify that it works as intended.  However, it would be very helpful for me to view the same results side by side with/without the filter applied.

Is there any way to map the same set of servlets and jsp files to two different context paths, so that the filter would only apply to one of them?

I don't want to deploy the war twice with the filter enabled/disabled, as I may be dropping this into various customer environments to test, and want to minimize the time spent configuring.

Comment: Why not just have a property that dynamically switches the filter 'off'  (or 'on') ?

Comment: I don't think I want this filter to be dynamically configurable from within the app.  If we can figure out how to do this, I can have both sets of data visible from a main page simultaneously

Comment: With Servlet 3.0, you can add a filter dynamically. But it would be the same as above. AFAIK there is no way you can have 2 context paths without loading the war twice.